# How to explain a relationship between Accuracy and F1 Score / F-Measure?

Tags: model, model-evaluation, accuracy, metric, f1

I am building a CNN model for pitch estimation using a song recording. For the evaluation metrics, I am using `Accuracy` and `F1 Score`. Sample of overall test result are given below using `mean` measurement. 
[image: CNN Sample test result]

Some notes:

1. `Val-Acc` is the validation accuracy. I am using this to see how well the model analyze new data that is not given during training.
2. `Delta acc` is the difference value between `accuracy` and `val-acc`.

Right now, I am wondering how can I explain the relationship between `Accuracy` and `F1 Score`. My supervisor said to me that accuracy is measured to get how accurate the model performs, and F1 is how well the model performs. Is the relationship really like that? May I get some insight on how to explain the relationship between them?

Comment: Please say more about how you are defining true positives, true negatives, false positives, and false negatives in your pitch-estimation system. My initial reaction is that pitch estimation would have more of a continuous measure of "accuracy" instead of the categorical yes/no classification results implicit in F1 score.

Comment: If this is an academic exercise to learn CNNs, perhaps your approach is okay. However, I would think that some kind of much simpler analysis in the frequency domain (Fourier or wavelet transforms) would be appropriate for this task. We have a signal processing Stack, dsp.Stackexchange, where you might be interested in posting.